# Unitary Central Character by Schur's Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory, characters

Consider an irreducible smooth representation $\pi$ of the group $G=GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ with center $Z$. Does there exist a unitary central character for $\pi$?

More precisely, is there a (quasi-)character $\omega: G \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ such that $\pi \otimes \omega$ when restricted to the center $Z$ is a unitary character for $Z$?
I find this result casually stated in many references, where they say it follows from Schur's lemma. But I am unable to see it directly from Schur's lemma.

Answer (score 4):

Let $Z$ be the center of $G$, and $\varpi: Z \rightarrow \mathbb C^{\ast}$ the central quasicharacter of $\pi$.  We can identify $Z$ with $\mathbb Q_p^{\ast}$.  You are asking whether there exists a quasicharacter $\chi$ of $G$ such that the quasicharacter

$$z \mapsto \varpi(z)\chi(z)$$

of $Z$ is unitary.  The answer is yes.  It is a fact that every quasicharacter of $\mathbb Q_p^{\ast}$ is of the form $x \mapsto c(x)|x|^s$, where $c$ is a quasicharacter of $\mathbb Z_p^{\ast}$ (automatically unitary since $\mathbb Z_p^{\ast}$ is compact), extended to all of $\mathbb Q_p^{\ast}$ via a choice of uniformizer, and $s$ a complex number.

Write $\varpi(x) = c(x)|x|^s$ as above, and let $\chi$ be the character of $G$ given by

$$g \mapsto |\operatorname{det}(g)|^{-\frac{s}{n}}$$

Upon restriction to $Z = \mathbb Q_p^{\ast}$, $\chi$ becomes the character $x \mapsto |x|^{-s}$, so we have $\varpi(x)\chi(x) = c(x)$, which is unitary.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the following from Garrett's *Automorphic Representations and L-functions*:

> Definition: A **central character** is simply a continuous group homomorphism $\omega : Z_A \to $ **$\mathbb C^\times$** where $Z$ is the center of a reductive linear group $G$ over a field $k$ and $Z_A$ denotes the *adele points* of $Z$.
>
> Triviality of $\omega \in Z_k$ is often assumed, resulting in the mapping $\omega : Z_A \to Z_k \diagup Z_A \to $ **$\mathbb C^\times$**. Furthermore, $\omega$ is said to be **unitary** when, $\forall z \in Z_A$, $|\omega(z)| = 1$

The key theorems are as follows:

> Theorem 4.1 ([Schur's Lemma over $\mathbb C$](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eteleman/math/RepThry.pdf)). If $V$ is an *irreducible complex* $G$*-representation*, then every linear operator $\phi : V \to V$ that commutes with $G$ is a scalar.
>
> *Proof*. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $\phi$ and assume that the eigenspace $E_\lambda$ is $G$-invariant. Then $v \in E_\lambda \implies \phi(v) = \lambda v,$ whence $\phi(gv) = g\phi(v) = g(\lambda v) = \lambda * gv$, so $gv \in E_\lambda$ (g was arbitrary). However, by irreducibility, this implies that $E_\lambda = V$, thus $\phi = \lambda \text{Id}$.

So, consider an irreducible smooth $G$-representation $\pi$.

> Theorem 3.8 ([Schur's Lemma](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/JLseminar/Notes/L2.pdf)). For a *td*-group $G$, any *irreducible smooth* $G$*-representation* $\pi$ satisfies End$_G$($\pi$) = $\mathbb C$.

Since a unitary central character is, by definition, a continuous group homomorphism $\omega : Z_A \to \mathbb C^\times$ such that $|\omega(z)| = 1 \space \forall z \in Z_A$, and, by Theorem 3.8, any  irreducible smooth $G$-representation $\pi$ satisfies End$_G$($\pi$) = $\mathbb C$, we can associate a *central character* $\omega_\pi(z) : Z \to \mathbb C^\times$ such that, for all matrix coefficients $f$ of $\pi$, $f(zh) = \omega_\pi(z)f(h).$ (commuting with G as a scalar, cf. Thm 4.1)

A matrix coefficient defined in **Definition 5.1** of [2](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/JLseminar/Notes/L2.pdf).

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question

Answer (score -1):

There is a central character $\omega:Z \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ by Schur, but it need not be unitary. E.g., consider $∣\text{det}∣$.